# gcc have problems with double rand?

Tags: c, gcc, random, double

I want generate double random value. Ok, I typed:

```
random_value = ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
```

Little checking with printf:

```
printf("rand: %f ", random_value);
```

Great, values from <0,1>. Then AFTER printf I wrote:

```
random_value *= range; // range have values from <0.05, 0.5>
printf("random_value: %f, range:%f\n", random_value, range);
```

And now it is started to be magic for me. FIRST printf (printf("rand: %f ", random_value);) started to giving me values ONLY from <0.8, 1>, where most values are near ~0.99. When I remove this line:

```
random_value *= range;
```

everything return to normal. Why this is happen?

code:

```
double random_value;
double range;
srand(time(NULL));
(...)
random_value = ((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
printf("rand: %f ", random_value);
random_value*=range;
printf("random_value: %f, range:%f\n", random_value, range);
```

Compile command:

```
gcc -lm ant.c -o ant -O0
```

gcc:

```
gcc (GCC) 4.7.2
```

system:

```
Linux 3.6.10-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Tue Dec 11 09:40:17 CET 2012 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Outputs without random_value *= range;

```
rand: 0.534583 random_value: 0.534583, range:0.156963
rand: 0.909061 random_value: 0.909061, range:0.156963
rand: 0.144450 random_value: 0.144450, range:0.156963
rand: 0.235249 random_value: 0.235249, range:0.156963
rand: 0.978194 random_value: 0.978194, range:0.156963
```

Outputs with random_value *= range;

```
rand: 0.965320 random_value: 0.570025, range:0.590504
rand: 0.991456 random_value: 0.155622, range:0.156963
rand: 0.957783 random_value: 0.392337, range:0.409631
rand: 0.970194 random_value: 0.122562, range:0.126327
rand: 0.980422 random_value: 0.132694, range:0.135344
```

Comment: IMHO this is pure random ;-) How many outputs with the line did you run? Five results are not statistically relevant: did you try to run it 1000 times?

Comment: In code, where is "(...)" I have initialization of range.
And of course I have made much more runs than 5, this outputs is only a few of whole results.

Comment: Offhand, are you calling `srand()` before each calculation? Perhaps try calling it **once** at program startup.

Comment: I am already calling srand() at startup (just once).

Comment: I'm somewhat at a loss then. I've looped 20 iterations with and without the mulop and what appears to be well-distributed random values from the `rand()` call. I can post the code if you desire.

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted a small program that demonstrates your problem. I don't think there's enough information here to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Post your *entire* code.  Post a [short, **self-contained**, **complete**, compilable example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Ok, I figure it out - it was my mistake. I've got bad if statement at the end, which stops my program. With `random_value*=range;` it was always return with `random_value = ~0.98`. Sorry guys for the troubles...